# tkinter mouse click counter won't break out of my countdown loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a little program in python using `tkinter`, to count the number of times the mouse clicks a button in 60 sec, but I have a problem: **I can't break the countdown loop**.

Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.bttn_clicks = 0
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.labelvariable = StringVar()
        self.labelvariable.set("60")

        self.thelabel = Label(self,textvariable = self.labelvariable,font=('Helvetica',50))
        self.thelabel.pack(side=TOP)

        self.firstButton = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.update_count)
        self.firstButton.pack(side=TOP)

    def update_count(self):
        self.bttn_clicks += 1
        self.firstButton["text"] = "Counter: " + str(self.bttn_clicks)
        if self.bttn_clicks == 1:
            countdown(1559)

def countdown(timeInSeconds):
    mins, secs = divmod(timeInSeconds, 60)
    timeformat = "{1:02d}".format(mins, secs)
    app.labelvariable.set(timeformat)
    root.after(1000, countdown, timeInSeconds-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Timer")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is a strange construction where you call the global function `countdown()` from inside the class `Application()`. Anyway: define a variable to account for if the counter is finished and only run the countdown if it is not finished yet. Set the variable finished when the time hits 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is keep everything within the class. Using an outside function just makes things harder to manage.

That said you should use `IntVar()` instead of string var as this will aid us in keeping track of the time.

My below code will check first if the timer is at 60. If so then start count down and add to counter. When the counter reaches zero the button has its command disabled and it no longer adds to the counter.

The other thing I changed was adding a manager method for the timer. Because we are now using `IntVar()` all we need to do is a `get()` command followed by a `-1` and an `after()` statement to keep the timer running until zero.

I also cleaned up your code a little to follow the PEP8 standard.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application,self).__init__(master)
        self.bttn_clicks = 0
        self.labelvariable = tk.IntVar()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.labelvariable.set(60)
        self.thelabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelvariable, font=('Helvetica',50))
        self.thelabel.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.firstButton = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.update_count)
        self.firstButton.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    def update_count(self):
        if self.labelvariable.get() == 60:
            self.manage_countdown()
        if self.labelvariable.get() != 0:
            self.bttn_clicks += 1
            self.firstButton.config(text="Counter: {}".format(self.bttn_clicks))
        else:
            self.firstButton.config(command=None)

    def manage_countdown(self):
        if self.labelvariable.get() != 0:
            self.labelvariable.set(self.labelvariable.get() - 1)
            self.after(1000, self.manage_countdown)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Timer")
    app = Application(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```